# Textarea youtube não reconhece valores injetados, apenas pressionados!

Tags: javascript, jquery

Boa tarde, estou criando uma parada de automatização para o youtube, onde cria-se o botão e quando a pessoa clica já adiciona todas informações no vídeo, informações que são sempre a mesma (Automatiza o padrão)

Pois bem, nas `textarea` que o youtube disponibiliza para titulo, descrição e etc, o sistema do youtube só reconhece que foi inserido algo quando eu faço uma alteração pressionando alguma tecla, apenas assim o botão **SALVAR** aparece para que eu salve as alterações.

Estou utilizando esses dois métodos e ambos resulta no mesmo, chega até adicionar no campo, mas se eu não digitar algo o youtube não reconhece que o textarea foi preenchido.

```
$( "textarea[placeholder*='Adicione um título']" ).val('Titulo do Vídeo JS');

$( "textarea[placeholder*='Adicione um título']" ).insertAtCaret("Titulo do Vídeo JS");
```

Cheguei a tentar utilizar uma função que simulava o pressionamento da tecla que eu achei no google mas não funcionou.

```
.triggerKeyPress([80, 78])
```

Alguém tem alguma sugestão do que eu posso fazer no código para que seja reconhecido a alteração no `textarea` da página pelo youtube?

Comment: Tentou simular um tab? Tipo, depois de preencher um input faz o focus em outro input qq e depois foca no btn de salvar pra ver se ele habilita

Comment: Só o focus com mais alterações posteriores não fez o youtube reconhecer como alteração não infelizmente